# Debounce same function with two different events

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I want to debounce same function in two diferent scenarios, when user clicks search button and when user stops typing. So if the user types cat and in less than 1 second he clicks 3 times search icon we will only search one time, after 1 second he stops clicking search button.

I tried this:

```
function debounce(your_func,time=1000){...}
function search_api(){...}

$("#my_input").on("input",
  debounce(function(){search_api()})
);

$("#search_button").on("click",
  debounce(function(){search_api()})
);
```

This works but not exacly what we want cause it debouce it "separately", so it debounces inputs by on hand and clicks to search on the other hand.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you trigger the same function so it will work as you expected.

You might think as the debounce function have a private var: timer(returned by setTimeout).

Each time you trigger this function it reset the old timer, and send a new SetTimeout, here is a simple version of debounce function.

```js
function debounce(func, timeout = 300){
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  };
}
function saveInput(){
  console.log('Saving data');
}
const processChange = debounce(() => saveInput());
```

If you separate two function , which means you create two new debounced function , and they both have a private timer and setTimeout function

Comment: Thanks for answering. You mean that when I do `const debounce_search = debbounce(search_api)`what I'm doing is create an instance of that function and every time I call `debounce_search` I'm calling the exact same func instance? Otherwise what normally happens is every time you call a function you are actually not calling same instance? Do you know the technical name of this so I can understand better?

Comment: This is called closure, which wrap the internal varables.

Comment: `const debounce_search = debbounce(search_api)` yes, you are calling the same function ,  this function returns a function

Everytime you call the function it will create another scope chain obtained by the function , I suggest you watch a light book <<https://kbpsystem777.github.io/You-Dont-Know-JS/>> .

Comment: Thank you very much for the documentation, very usefull ^

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution but don't know why is working despite reading a lot of documentation about functions and callbacks:

```
function debounce(your_func,time=1000){...}
function search_api(){...}
const debounce_search = debbounce(search_api)

$("#my_input").on("input",
  debounce_search
);

$("#search_button").on("click",
  debounce_search
);
```